# In Built Video Streaming Facilities Available in DOTNETNUKE?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-6, dotnetnuke-settings, dotnetnuke-7

In Built Video Streaming Facilities Available in DOTNETNUKE?

Comment: You can take a look at the Media module http://dnnmedia.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNN hasn't got any build-in video streaming. There are a number of modules that allow you to hook up to a video, show a (categorized) video library. You can store these video's locally on your site, or on some kind of service.
Personally, I have good experiences with vimeo (plus version). E.G. with Vimeo you can tweak the private settings in such a way that the video can only be played from you own site.

Comment: I had the same issues.  We wanted to stream videos, but the content was sensitive, so only people that logged in could see. Streaming video is not as easy as you would think.